# Guidance required with SurfaceView and using different classes for sprites

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview, surface

I have a very basic knowledge of android studio and have only developed apps using buttons and other triggers. I am looking to create an application where I can use moving sprites. I think, from what is online, I should be looking at using SurfaceViews however cant seem to get my head around anything relating to SurfaceViews or creating and using different classes for sprites.

I am currently trying to simply change the colour of my activity using SurfaceView however cannot even manage to do that at the moment! ANY help is appreciated, in answers please explain what is being done so I can understand the answers! :P

Code bellow:

**Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Frenchie.TestSpaceGame.GameActivity">

    <com.Frenchie.TestSpaceGame.GameView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**GameActivity.java**

```
package com.Frenchie.TestSpaceGame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GameView gameView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameView = new GameView(this);

        setContentView(gameView);

    }
}
```

**GameView.java**

```
package com.Frenchie.TestSpaceGame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {
        //check if surface is valid
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {

            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a blank black screen at the moment when GameActivity is opened.